# Setting pin marks which remain permanent after disconnect from Google Earth

Tags: google-earth

How can I set a permanent pin mark which remains in place after I disconnect from Google Earth?

I've been able to do this in the past, but after resetting my hard drive, I can no longer fix a permanent pin mark.

Comment: See https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148142?hl=en

Comment: Are you using Google Earth Pro (the desktop installed version), or the newer Google Earth for web & mobile?